# itextpdf : PdfPTable dont takes height

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itextpdf

I migrated my publisher core from itext-2.... to itextpdf-5.5.6

In itext-2 I had an image into cell of a PdfPTable an my table's celle had same size that image.
Now, in itextpdf-5.5.6 image have small size like that cell.

For example I use

```
table.setTotalWidth(450);
```

and in core itextpdf it calculate height too :

```
//ITEXTPDF
calculateWidths();
calculateHeights();
```

calculateHeight call to getRowHeight

```
getRowHeight(k, true);
```

and it does not do the same that in itext-2 :

- itext returns 400
- itextpdf returns 23

I debbuged for itextpdf and found that in pdfLine.getMaxSize(..) there is the following code :

```
if (chunk.isImage()) {
  Image img = chunk.getImage();
  if (chunk.changeLeading()) {
    float height = chunk.getImageHeight() + chunk.getImageOffsetY() + img.getSpacingBefore();
    image_leading = Math.max(height, image_leading);
    }
  }
```

and in the case of itext i have no condition like that :

```
if (chunk.changeLeading()){......}
```

Is there an average for solve it ?

Comment: Try using img.scaleAbsolute or img.scaleToFit apis

Comment: iText 5.5.6 has much more ways to add an image to a cell. Depending on which way you choose, the cell shrinks to the size of the cell or the cell expands to the size of the image. There are many variations. To explain these variations in my book, I wrote the [XMen](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=84) example. It adds different images to the table using different techniques, leading to a different result. Which technique are you using?

Comment: I dont know yet, because my project is very wide. I just made migration to itextpdf and this has impacted on the image resolution in table. I just wanted to know if there is any specific action to do for itextpdf for image resolution

Comment: I modified my question and gave more details

Answer (score 0):

I found where was problem :

```
Paragraph para = new Paragraph(new Chunk((Image) element, 0, 0, Boolean.FALSE));
```

the last parameter of chunk is changeLeading and it just had to change as Boolean.TRUE

Thanks everybody for your responses